# C# operator ?: how to simplify basic if statement in one expression

Tags: c#, expression, operator-keyword

Is there any way to simplify this expression:

I want to do this:

```
d = ( a == "x" ? b : a )
```

i can use three lines of code:

```
d = a;
if(a == "x")
   d = b
```

Can i do it in one line of code/one expression, without using **a** twice?

Comment: Start with better names for your variables ;)

Comment: I don't see how it could be simpler than the version using the conditional operator

Comment: What's the point of trying to 'simplify' it further? (I doubt it can be)

Comment: Less code is not better code.

Comment: There is no penalty (in this case) for using a twice.  What's your real issue?

Comment: what can be simpler than d = ( a == "x" ? b : a ) ?

Comment: Is it any operator that can do:
d = ( a == "X" ?if_not_first_compare_operator_value_else_b b)

Comment: `if(d == "x")` doesn't use `a` twice :)

Comment: If `a` is the result of a heavy operation, like a query or some I/O, you should cache it in a different variable.

Comment: My betting is you'd end up with the same binary. That's why they're called *optimising* compilers. I'd always code for clarity.

Comment: Without any context this is a question that will lead to wild discussion. It's a good candidate for "not constructive" close votes. Now, if you told us **why** you wanted this, I'd bet you'd get more informative feedback.

Comment: @plinth Well, if `a` here is representing an expression that causes side effects it's possible that it can't be used twice when composing the larger expression.  That's the only sensible reason I can think of for not wanting to use it twice.

Comment: if the variable a is an function, there will be cases in which i call the function twice

Comment: You can extract method, then you will have this operations in one row :P

Comment: You need to post a more specific example. It sounds like these variables represent something that needs to be handled in a particular fashion. Without knowing what they are, it's impossible to suggest the correct solution.

Comment: Just trying to know if there is an operator for that. 
To compare null values there are an specific operator: 
?? operator

Comment: Why are you putting the crucial detail that a is actually a function call in comments. Put it in the question. It's the most important fact.

Answer (score 9):

> Can i do it in one line of code/one expression, without using a twice?

Yes, but you really shouldn't:

```
d = new[] { a }.Except("x").DefaultIfEmpty(b);
```

I'm *really* not seriously suggesting this - just pointing out that your criteria aren't really a good metric for "readable".

If you find you do this frequently, you could write an extension method, e.g.

```
public static string OrDefaultFor(this string input,
                                  string invalidInput,
                                  string replacement)
{
    return input == invalidInput ? replacement : input;
}
```

Then:

```
d = a.OrDefaultFor("x", b);
```

Choose a better name if you can :)

Comment: I really like that answer but I dont think that this is a better approach than what OP has already mentioned!!

Comment: That is awesome. Unreadability and all! ;)

Comment: Question doesn't talk about readability. Just simplification. One programmer's simple, is another programmer's complex. Who knows what simple means here?!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Jon was pretty clear that it's *not* a better approach. It's just an answer to the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Normally _simple_ is rather a synonym for _readable_ than for _short_.

Comment: @AndrewBarber:- I think OP has asked for simplification but not for an alternate solution. (Mind it that I really liked this solution) but that is not what OP has askd for!!

Comment: @TimSchmelter But that doesn't appear to be the case here. The question already contains very readable code. So it looks like simple in this context means something else. Perhaps it means "only naming `a` once".

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that `a` causes side effects of some sort, and for that reason can't be used twice.  (Maybe it is a function, or property, etc.)

You were close with your second code snippet, but you'd want to use:

```
d = a;
if(d == "x")
   d = b
```

The key point there is using `d` in the `if`, not `a` again.

If you really want to reduce the number of lines of code you can use this instead:

```
d = a;
if(d == "x") d = b
```

Congrats, you're now down to two lines of code.  Beyond that, anything that you try to do to "simplify" the code will likely cause more harm than good in some way.  As it is the intent of the code is quite clear; make a local copy of the results of `a`, then determine whether to use `a` or `b` via an `if`.

Comment: this will resolve the side effects, and in the cases of a is an process consuming function. The main question is that an new C# operator can resolve this in one line of code.

Comment: @user1863603 The existing code is quite simple, and it's a rather uncommon use case.  There is no need to introduce a new C# operator just to handle this one example.  You could create a function to do it if you wanted, but the calling code wouldn't be significantly simpler, and unless you used it a lot that would add more code/work than you'd save.  As for the code sample you posted, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = (d = a) == "x" ? b : d;
```

As previously noted, the question is wrong and the answer is worse.

Comment: @user1863603 - The colon is not optional in the C# ?: conditional operator.